# Enterprise distribution of an iOS app from a third party developer

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I've been asked if we can distribute an iOS app internally (via AirWatch) which has been developed by a third party. We can't use the App Store is because the developer is re-branding their app for our company.

So they would have to sign their app with our Distribution Certificate but what is the safest way (for us) to allow them to do this?

Comment: For how many people you want to distribute the app?

Comment: @Imad about 400

Comment: You can purchase [Apple Developer Enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/) for $299/yr and distribute the apps using Airwatch is the most secure way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sign the app yourself. so the 3-rd party developer have no access to your certificates.

1. Enroll to [Apple Developer Enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/) .
2. Create enterprise certificate.
3. Create provisioning profile and any other certificates that the app 
   needs (the developer should know which extras are needed).
4. Get the ipa file (the app) from the developer.
5. Resign the ipa with your own certificate you created earlier - to do so use the [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) tool.
6. Diatribute the app via your MDM (AirWatch).

Comment: Been looking at iResign just now, hasn't been maintained for a few years though. Do you use this tool yourself for re-signing from Developer to Enterprise Distribution? Any problems? Gotchas?

Comment: I've been using it, didn't encounter any problems... if you have issues let me know